# Difference in bash printf output between run script and source script

Tags: bash, unicode, printf

I can't seem to find the difference between a script run two different ways.

Here's the script (named `test.sh`):

```
#! /bin/bash
printf "%b\n" "\u5A"
```

When the script is sourced:

```
. test.sh
> Z         ## Result I want ##
```

When the script is run:

```
./test.sh
> \u5A      ## Result I get ##
```

I want the run script to give the results of the sourced script...  what setting do I need to set/change?

Comment: What I'm looking for is some environment variable (eg. `export LANG=en_CA.UTF-8`), emacs setting (eg. `set output-meta on`), set/shopt option (eg. `shopt -s xpg_echo`). etc... to make the script translate like printf's `%b` should do. Instead it prints it out as if I had used `%s`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HAHA!!!** I finally traced down the problem! Read ahead if interested (leave the page if not).

These are the ***only*** command that will translate `\u` properly:

```
. ./test.sh                         ## Sourcing the script, hash-bang = #! /bin/sh
. ./test.bash                       ## Sourcing the script, hash-bang = #! /bin/bash
./test                              ## Running the script with no hash-bang
```

All of the following produce identical results in that they do *NOT* translate `\u`:

```
./test.sh                           ## Script is run from an interactive shell but in a non-interactive shell

## test.sh has first line: #! /bin/sh
/bin/sh -c "./test.sh"              ## Running the script in a non-interactive sh shell
/bin/sh -lc "./test.sh"             ## Running the script in a non-interactive, login sh shell
/bin/sh -c ". ./test.sh"            ## Sourcing the file in a non-interactive sh shell
/bin/sh -lc ". ./test.sh"           ## Sourcing the file in a non-interactive, login sh shell

## test.bash has first line: #! /bin/bash
/bin/bash -c "./test.bash"          ## Running the script in a non-interactive bash shell
/bin/bash -lc "./test.bash"         ## Running the script in a non-interactive, login bash shell
/bin/bash -c ". ./test.bash"        ## Sourcing the file in a non-interactive bash shell
/bin/bash -lc ". ./test.bash"       ## Sourcing the file in a non-interactive, login bash shell

## And from ***tripleee*** (thanks btw):
/bin/sh --norc; . ./test.sh         ## Sourcing from an interactive sh shell without the ~/.bashrc file read
/bin/bash --norc; . ./test.bash     ## Sourcing from an interactive bash shell without the ~/.bashrc file read
```

The only way to get proper translation is to run the script *without* a *hash-bang*... and I finally figured out why! Without a *hash-bang* my system chooses the default shell, which btw is *NOT* `/bin/bash`... it turns out to be `/opt/local/bin/bash`... two different versions of bash!

Finally, I removed the OSX `/bin/bash` [v3.2.48(1)] and replaced it with the MacPorts `/opt/local/bin/bash` [v4.2.10(2)] and now running the script works! It actually solved about 10-15 other problems I've had (like `${var,,}`, `read sN1 char`, `complete -EC "echo ' '"`, and a host of other commands I have scattered throughout my scripts, `~/.bashrc` amd `~/.profile`). Honestly, I really should have noticed when my scripts using associative arrays suddenly crapped out on me... **how stupid can I get!?**

I've been using bash v4 for a looong time now, and my Lion upgrade went and down-graded bash back to v3 (get with the program Apple!)... ugh, I feel so ashamed! Everyone still using bash v3, **upgrade!!** bash v4 is has many, many beautiful upgrades over version 3. Type **`bash --version`** to see what version you are running. One advantage is now bash can translate `\uHEX` into ***Unicode!***

Comment: The shebang makes no difference if you `source` the file, it's just a comment then. The currently running shell, whichever it is, will be interpreting the commands in the file (that's what `source` aka `.` does).

Answer (score 2):

You are probably getting different versions of printf; the script you are sourcing from is probably a /bin/sh script, not a Bash script proper?

Comment: Verrrry close tripleee!! Turns out I had 2 different versions of bash running... I posted the answer. +1 anyway for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be using `\x` instead of `\u`? `printf "%b\n" "\x5A"` works fine in both cases for me.

Comment: +1, note that `\u` expects an unsigned decimal, but `5A` is hex.

Comment: I have a script containing long lists of unicode characters that I want to have printed on the terminal properly. I can't use UTF-8 (`\xE2\x88\x9E...`) for each multi-byte character instead of `\u2221E`. I simply used `\u5A` as an example, but `\u50` is fine too. I want the script to translate it, not spit it back at me. If you're running OSX, then open the Character Viewer in the input menu... every value for unicode is a hex value. U+221E (for instance, for infinity) I have _always_ worked with hex since day 1 using `\u` within many scripts... it has always taken a hex value normally for me.

Comment: In any case, this answer doesn't explain why sourcing the script and running the script gave different results. That's the real oddity here.

Comment: Turns out I've been using bash 4, which *does* accept hex for `\u`... I've never known older versions do not like hex but it turns out any version below 4 craps out with `\uHEX`

Answer (score 1):

(Totally different idea here, so I'm posting it as another answer.)

Try running these at the command line:

```
builtin printf "%b\n" "\u5A"
/usr/bin/env printf "%b\n" "\u5A"
```

`printf` is both a shell builtin and an executable, and you may be getting different ones depending on whether you source or run the script. To find out, insert this in the script and run it each way:

```
type printf
```

While you're at it, you may as well insert this line too:

```
echo $SHELL
```

That will reveal if you're getting different shells, per tripleee.

Comment: Thanks Tom for the help! Focusing of printf is sooo close to the answer... turns out 2 different bash versions... +1 for all the help (and research)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the space in the first line, I seem to recall that can cause problems. Offhand I'd guess that because of that space, you're not getting bash, but sh.

Comment: The space is there on purpose so as `"\u5A"` is an argument to `printf`. I get the same results with `printf $'\u5A'` and `printf "\u5A"` and `echo -e "\u5A"` and `echo $'\u5A'` ... all of which have removed the space.

Comment: He means the space before /bin/bash. See also my answer.

Comment: @tripleee is correct: I was saying the shebang should be `#!/bin/bash`, without a space. I thought I had read somewhere that the space cuased some kind of problem. I just spent some time googling and I can't find anything about that, so I'm probably wrong. Still, it's worth a try and doesn't do any harm.

Comment: Well, I tried it and got the exact same results... however, you may have inadvertently stumbled on the problem. **By removing the _hash-bang_ line altogether, the problem is fixed!** 

 I tried changing it to `#! /bin/sh`, `#!/bin/sh`, `#! /bin/bash`, and `#!/bin/bash`, no differences.

Comment: Anyone know why this strange behaviour is happening? No *hash-banger* and boom! Everything works!

Comment: For the record, a space in the shebang should be completely harmless on any remotely modern system.

Answer (score 0):

Glad you solved it.  Still, you might be looking for a portable solution.

Assuming you are always using the same formatting string, we can just discard it, and use something like this;

```
printf () {
  # Discard format string
  shift
  perl -CSD -le '
    print map { s/^\\u//; chr(hex($_)) } @ARGV' "$@"
}
```

Edit to add: You would simply add this function definition at the beginning of your existing script, overriding the builtin `printf`. Obviously, if you also use `printf` for other stuff, this special-purpose replacement isn't good enough.

You could rename the function to `uprintf` or something, still. It merely translates a sequence of hex codes to the corresponding Unicode characters, discarding any `\u` prefix.